# How do I change the color of the background lines, the structural ones

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I need to change the color of the background lines in dygraphs. Because I want them to be solid black instead of grey. Otherwise our printer won't display them properly.

There's no mention of a CSS class that refers to these lines, But I'm sure you guys know some genius way to find out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the following [site](https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-axis-options.html), you can utilize the **axisLineColor** and **gridLineColor** options to change the colors of axis and grid lines respectively.

**Example**:

```
dygraph(AirPassengers, main = "Airline Passengers / Month") %>%
  dyAxis("x", drawGrid = FALSE) %>%
  dyAxis("y", label = "Passengers (Thousands)") %>%
  dyOptions(includeZero = TRUE, 
            axisLineColor = "navy", 
            gridLineColor = "lightblue")
```

If you want to want to modify labels, title colors, you can do it, via CSS Styling classes.

The CSS [classes](https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-css-styling.html) for the chart labels are:

```
Title: .dygraph-label .dygraph-title
x-axis label: .dygraph-label .dygraph-xlabel
y-axis label: .dygraph-label .dygraph-ylabel
y2-axis label: .dygraph-label .dygraph-y2label
```

The axis labels also get CSS classes:

```
x-axis: .dygraph-axis-label .dygraph-axis-label-x
y-axis: .dygraph-axis-label .dygraph-axis-label-y
y2-axis: .dygraph-axis-label .dygraph-axis-label-y .dygraph-axis-label-y2
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I didn't know there was another site containing Dygraph documentation. I expected the main site to contain everything because there was already a lot in there.